# Error when solve function to knit. How can i fix it?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to make html markdown. 
The code is woking but when i try to knit it just not working

I tried to change some default value. It is not working.
And I already update my R studio and Knitr, rmarkdown packages.

```
d3 <- (as.matrix(data1[1,]- data1[2,])
       %*% solve(S)
       %*% t(as.matrix(data1[1,]-data1[2,])))
d3 <- sqrt(d3)
print(d3)
```

> Error in solve.default(S): Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly
>   singular: U[2, 2]= 0 Calls ... withVisible -> eval -> eval
>   -> solve -> solve.default Execution halted

Comment: Hello there. Welcome to SO. The error message shown relates to the matrix `S`. R is saying it can not solve (get the inverse of) `S`.

Comment: Please make reproducible data(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)